# Visual Studio issue with recognising variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Okay so in short:

I declare a variable, say

```
string str = "Random";
```

then I try to perform any sort of operation whatsoever, say

```
str.ToLower();
```

And neither visual studio, nor intellisense recognise it at all.
VS gives me the name "str" does not exist in the current context. This happened right after I installed xamarin but I'm not sure if it's related.

Also this issue would not occur if I was inside a method, just when I'm directly inside a class.

This is my code:

```
public class Program {
   public void randomMethod() {
      string str2 = "Random";
      str.ToUpper(); //this line shows no errors
   }

   string str = "Random";
   str.ToLower(); //this line does show the error
}
```

str would be underlined red and the warning mentioned above would appear.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Provide more context.  *Where* are you declaring that variable?  *Where* are you trying to access that variable?  We need enough code to understand what you're doing.

Comment: Have you tried running a repair on VS?

Comment: How can I do that @DeanOC

Comment: You can't reference a field directly in the class like that which is why it is red underlined only when you try to access it as such. You need to be inside of a method

Comment: code like `str.ToLower`  must be in a function. You have it inside the class definition.

Comment: @HsenShamseddine, it seems your issue is solved and str.ToLower() must inside a function not directly under the class, please mark the helpful reply when you have free time, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you even point the issue out yourself

you cannot do this

```
public class Program {
   string str = "Random";
   str.ToLower(); //this line does show the error
}
```

when would you expect that code to run?

You *must* put executable code inside a function. You point out that this works.

I cannot propose a fix since I do not know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is a scope issue:

```
public class Program {
   public void randomMethod() { //method scope starts
      string str2 = "Random";
      str.ToUpper(); //this line shows no errors
   } //method scope ends

   string str = "Random";  //this is a class field, but is missing an accessibility level
   str.ToLower(); //this line SHOULD show an error, because you can't do this in a class
}
```